# For Loop with 2 variables, but wanting to only enumerate 1 of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

In Python 3, I'm wanting to conduct a For loop on two variables, but using the enumerate function for only the first one. It looks like this:

```
for no, (r, j) in enumerate(all_accepted_results), all_accepted_accuracies:
    plt.plot(r, label = 'Forecast #%d - Accuracy %f'%(no + 1, all_accepted_accuracies[j] ))
```

where `no` would be the number from the enumerate function, `r` would be the actual value from the list `all_accepted_results` that gets plotted on the chart, and `j` would be the actual value from the list `all_accepted_accuracies` that gets added as a label to the legend.

Right now I receive the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I have also tried:

```
for no, r, j in enumerate(all_accepted_results), all_accepted_accuracies:
```

...and receive the same error as above, only "(expected 3)", and also tried:

```
for no, (r, j) in enumerate(all_accepted_results, all_accepted_accuracies):
```

...which got me the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

so I'm at a loss for what to try next. Obviously I'm just trying to plot the r value from above, and in the legend of the plot have it say which forecast # it is, and its corresponding accuracy number.

I will be heading to work shortly but will re-visit here if anyone has any ideas for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) 'em all:

```
for (no, r), j in zip(enumerate(all_accepted_results), all_accepted_accuracies):
```

Note that it's `(no, r), j`, and not `no, (r, j)`, because `enumerate` yields tuples like `(no, r)`, *not* only the consecutive integers `no`.

Your code:

```
for ... in enumerate(all_accepted_results), all_accepted_accuracies:
```

...is basically the same as this:

```
>>> for a in 1,2,3,4,5:
...  print(a)
... 
1
2
3
4
5
>>>
```

The part after `in` is actually a *tuple* that, in your case, contains two elements: the `enumerate` object and `all_accepted_accuracies`, so you'll end up iterating over these two objects.

Comment: You could write this as `enumerate(zip(...)):`, so that `no, (r, j)` works.

Comment: Works! Thanks so much for the explanation too!